# Lazy load Images, but use the standard syntax for img elements

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm making a tiny lazy loader that currently looks like this:

```
<!-- an image -->

<div data-image-src="http://lorempixel.com/450/350/" width="450" height="350" style="width:450px;height:350px" ></div>
<script>
    // Lazy load all images
    var elements = document
        .querySelectorAll('[data-image-src]');

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
        var image   = document.createElement("img"),
            parent  = element.parentElement,
            src     = element.getAttribute('data-image-src');

        for (var attr in element.attributes) {
            if ( element.attributes.hasOwnProperty(attr) && attr !== 'length' ) {
                image.setAttribute(element.attributes[attr].name, element.attributes[attr].value);
            }
        }

        image.src = src;
        image.onload = function() { parent.replaceChild(image, element); }
    });
</script>
```

As you can see the image element is really ugly. I'd like to just cancel loading for `<img>` elements in the header, and fire it in the footer, instead of using a `<div>` to act as placeholder. Hopefully without having to omit the `[src]` attribute on the image.

I'm particularly interested in that they have the `src` attribute. My goal is to be able to use image tags with valid, regular syntax, and ALSO be able to lazy load them.

Is this possible, maybe by replacing one of the `HTMLImageElement` prototype methods temporarily?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="1x1.png" data-image-src="http://lorempixel.com/450/350/" width="450" height="350" style="width:450px;height:350px" />
```

Why not use a transparent placeholder, and then swap out the src on your load event?

Comment: Well the question is more aimed at achieving lazy load with images that have normal syntax